# search box or autocomplete text box for search UL list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need a search box or autocomplete textbox to search a specified value from the  list 
using JQUERY OR JAVASCRIPT.

for example:
BY default, all the values in the list are displayed under the text box.

when i enter "a" in the text box means, the the word starts from "a" are displayed.

```
<input id="tags" />
<div id="xxx">
<ul id="autocompletes1">
<li><a href="index.html">Acura</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">BMW</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Cadillac</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Chrysler</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Dodge</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work with your UL listing, however you will be better off using javascript plugins...

```
$('#tags').on('keyup',function(e){
  // cache all the tag elements in an array
  var tagElems = $('#autocompletes1').children();

  // hide all tags
  $(tagElems).hide();


  for(var i = 0; i < tagElems.length; i++){ // loop through all tagElements
    var tag = $(tagElems).eq(i);

    if(($(tag).text().toLowerCase()).indexOf($(this).val().toLowerCase()) === 0){
      // if element's text value starts with the hint show that tag element
      $(tag).show();
    }
  }
});
```

[**`Working Example`**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLV3y/1/) without tag selection logic...

[**`Example with tag selection logic`**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLV3y/4/)

Comment: @Фейсал Сайед, dude excellent code, but would like to add like instead of === 0 , try with !== -1, so that we can get any in between match too, I bow for your example.

Comment: @soundarrajan, one more improvement, place the line var tagElems = $('#autocompletes1').children(); above the keyup event like var tagElems = $('#autocompletes1 > li');

Comment: @SAM `=== 0` is intentional to check from beginning of the string, though one can change that to `!== -1` to search in whole text. I added `tagElems` variable inside the event binding to prevent polluting global scope. Also this makes the code portable between files, modules etc, however user can do the optimization as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [];
    $('#autocompletes1 li').each(function(){
        availableTags.push($(this).text());
    });


    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HjWQ/3/)

Note: have to use jquery ui

Comment: nice SAM..but without display the pop up, i need to collapse the list depends upon the filter result..

Answer (score -1):

```
var sources = [];
$('span').each(function(i,ele){
  sources.push({'label': $(ele).text(), 'value' : i});
});
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: sources
});
```

**[Untidy JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/VMSEt/3/)**

Comment: HI..i want to search,which is inside the <ul> list.so what can i give instead of "sources" in source:sources.

Comment: nice ....but without display the pop up, i need to collapse the list depends upon the filter result..