# Sorting dropdown textbox in html/css

Tags: php, html, css

I have an array containing many names in PHP. I would like to allow a user type some text in a text box as shown in the image below. When the user types in these data, I would like my text box to show a drop down list, where a user can click on a name and select it (instead of having to type the whole name). I am new to HTML and not sure if this is possible. I can’t use scripting language in my website since the sever blocks them. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need something like Datalists.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

```
<input list="names">

<datalist id="names">
<?php foreach ($names as $name) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
<?php } ?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me with an example. That's exactly what I was looking for. you are a big help

Comment: Also, you can use something like asort($names) before the foreach, to sort your array by value. This way it would always be displayed in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is a duplicate question.

The following thread contains a jsfiddle example that should provide enough information on how to do the desired functionality.

[search box or autocomplete text box for search UL list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463721/search-box-or-autocomplete-text-box-for-search-ul-list)